# Mysql how to select rows by 2 criteria and only show the ones where rest of the columns = null?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called item configurations and it consists of ItemID, Color, Weight, Height.

If I do a select * from ItemConfigurations where color = 'red' and Weight = '100', I get more rows than I want.

For instance:

```
row 1: item 234, color red and weight 100 AND HEIGHT = 10
row 2: item 234, color red and weight 100
row 3: item 234, color red and weight 100 AND HEIGHT = 20 AND fabric = cloth
```

I wanted only the second row (red/100), but since the other rows also matches those criteria, they are also in the result.

The number of configurations (=columns) can go up in time when people add more things like for instance fabric = cloth.

So I can't just say select * from ItemConfigurations where color = 'red' and Weight = '100' and HEIGHT = null because once the fabric is added, I would also have to add fabric = null to the where clause.

Any advice about how to only get only the row I want (row 2 with where color = red and weight = 100) with a growing number of columns in this table?

I thought about adding a 'check' column and just insert the sum of all the values in the columns upon inserting / updating a row in the table and putting that check into my select. But it doesn't feal like the right way to go about this. (all values are integers btw as it's normalized)

Although I work with php, I would like to do the above inside a mysql query. Hopefully someone knows how to got about this.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...` try this

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya `TOP 1` won't work its MySql so you would use the LIMIT keyword `SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1;`, however don't think this is the answer OP wants

Comment: Thanks. but doesn't top 1 only limit the result set to the first row? Maybe I understand you wrong please tell me. I just want the row where only color = red and weight = 100 and all other columns are null.

Comment: Alternatively put a `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query

Comment: I edited my question so it's hopefully more clear what I'm after. Thanks for the top 1 and limit 1 answers! But that won't help me, I think....

Comment: How are you building the SQL? is this a `stored routine` you are passing params into `OR` are you using something like `PHP` to compose the SQL?

Comment: I’m using PHP with a pdo statement?

Comment: Then thats your answer. use `PHP` to construct the where clause for you.